# Squishy raw pork - gone bad?

Tags: food-safety, pork

I bought some pork loin chops and went to open the package and part of the meat was really squishy. I repackaged it and put it in the freezer to throw away later. I didn't notice any smell but didn't get too close to it and it looks fine otherwise. The best before date is three days from now. Is it common for meat to get squishy like this? I don't think it was tenderized. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An important part of practicing food safety on your own kitchen, is looking out for any "red flags" in raw ingredients that may have the potential to sicken.

If something doesn't smell right, doesn't look right, or as in your case, doesn't feel right; it is a red flag that you should pay attention to. It might be safe to eat, but why take any chances?

Supermarkets have been known to treat expired meat with ammonia or bleach, and then repackage it with an extended expiration date. Such despicable practices are hopefully rare, but pre-seasoning soon-to-expire meats and poultry, and repackaging with a later date is quite common.

You don't need to save the meat itself, but keep the package label (and receipt if you still have it), and bring it back to your store for a refund. Most stores will give you your money back with no hassle.

Comment: Thank you. I just called the store and they said it's fine! I'm not sure I agree though. The chicken drumsticks I got at the same place feel a bit soft too but maybe I am noticing it too much. My fridge is cold enough but possibly the store's isn't even though it's really popular.

Comment: Still not going to eat the pork chops!

Comment: If the texture is not right, it isn't fine. The store can't accurately assess food safety over the phone. If they don't make it right with you, I'd look for someplace else to shop.